# how are js-modules loaded with respect to <script> js files in index?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

For plugins, if a javascript file is loaded through  is it loaded before or after the  imports in index.html?

Say in my plugin I have a line window.something() = function() {blah; blah;} and someone using the plugin also assigns a function to window.something in a  file they have. Which of those window.somethings()s is called first? The one in js-module or the one in index.html?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add some clarity to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the last script that gets run is the one that gets precedence. Which platform are you gargeting?

Some more details about how `js-module` scripts are specified is at the link below:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#js-module

> Most plugins include one or more JavaScript files. Each  tag corresponds to a JavaScript file, and prevents the plugin's users from having to add a  tag for each file. Do not wrap the file with cordova.define, as it is added automatically. The module is wrapped in a closure, with module, exports, and require in scope, as is normal for AMD modules. Nesting  elements within  declares platform-specific JavaScript module bindings.